# ReactJS MUI styles overwrite my custom MUI styles (shared-lib) when importing both shared-lib and MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a shared library in react with storybook.

Inside of this library I'm using the MUI V5 Button and changing some of its styles using css modules.

I have ran the "build&pack" script inside my library and this has created a tgz package which i have imported in a new react application which consumes my library (inside my dependencies)

```
"dependencies": {
 "shared-react": "/Users/..../shared-react-1.0.0.tgz"
}
```

And then if i import it in my app like this:

```
import './App.css';
import {ButtonCSSModule} from 'shared-react'
import * as React from 'react';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ButtonCSSModule variant="contained" disabled={false}></ButtonCSSModule>
        </div>);
}

export default App;
```

it works:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASi5N.png)

But if I import for example the MUI button in addition to my custom button

```
import {Button} from '@mui/material';
import './App.css';
import {ButtonCSSModule} from 'shared-react'
import * as React from 'react';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <ButtonCSSModule variant="contained" disabled={false}></ButtonCSSModule>
            <Button variant={"contained"}>New Button From Material</Button>
        </div>);
}

export default App;
```

then the style gets overwritten by MUI styles
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzT2p.png)

Is it possible to somehow always overwrite the `button` style from `@mui/material`  with my own styles (from my shared library)?
like somehow export the css files and import them inside my new app and then anytime someone uses a material button it will use the styles I have created?

this is the link to my library I have created

Github link to library: https://github.com/itzikd15/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing Css injecting ordeer
Wrap your app with `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>` from mui with injectFirst Prop